# How to Unzip a file with dynamic name using batch file?

Tags: batch-file, server

All i am trying is to automate the unzip process through batch file and scheduling the same, it worked when the file name is static (mentioned below)

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd /d %~dp0
Call :UnZipFile "D:\QlikSense\Data\OBL\FTP\" "D:\QlikSense\Data\OBL\FTP\T56Q_OBL001_20200312111131.zip"
Call :UnZipFile "D:\QlikSense\Data\OBL\FTP\" "D:\QlikSense\Data\OBL\FTP\T56Q_OBL002_20200312111131.zip"

exit /b

:UnZipFile <ExtractTo> <newzipfile>
set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
>%vbs%  echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>>%vbs% echo If NOT fso.FolderExists(%1) Then
>>%vbs% echo fso.CreateFolder(%1)
>>%vbs% echo End If
>>%vbs% echo set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
>>%vbs% echo set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(%2).items
>>%vbs% echo objShell.NameSpace(%1).CopyHere(FilesInZip)
>>%vbs% echo Set fso = Nothing
>>%vbs% echo Set objShell = Nothing
cscript //nologo %vbs%
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%

timeout 20
```

But the same is not working when it is made for **Dynamic** using ' * ' (find the code below)

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd /d %~dp0
Call :UnZipFile "D:\QlikSense\Data\OBL\FTP\" "D:\QlikSense\Data\OBL\FTP\T56Q_OBL001_*.zip\"
Call :UnZipFile "D:\QlikSense\Data\OBL\FTP\" "D:\QlikSense\Data\OBL\FTP\T56Q_OBL002_*.zip\"

exit /b

:UnZipFile <ExtractTo> <newzipfile>
set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
>%vbs%  echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>>%vbs% echo If NOT fso.FolderExists(%1) Then
>>%vbs% echo fso.CreateFolder(%1)
>>%vbs% echo End If
>>%vbs% echo set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
>>%vbs% echo set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(%2).items
>>%vbs% echo objShell.NameSpace(%1).CopyHere(FilesInZip)
>>%vbs% echo Set fso = Nothing
>>%vbs% echo Set objShell = Nothing
cscript //nologo %vbs%
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%

timeout 20
```

The following is the error reflecting on the case

> C:\Users\TECHADMIN\Appdata\Local\Temp\4_.vbs(6, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'objShell.NameSpace(...)'

Comment: It is called "asterix in file name".

Comment: i am sorry ! i couldnt understand, can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Sorry for the quick comment. The official name of this kind of filenames is not "dynamic". It is called "asterix".

Comment: This looks awfully complex. Can I suggest using PowerShell?

Comment: @JamesZ Yes please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd /d "%~dp0"
Call :UnZipFile "D:\QlikSense\Data\OBL\FTP\" "D:\QlikSense\Data\OBL\FTP\T56Q_OBL001_*.zip"
Call :UnZipFile "D:\QlikSense\Data\OBL\FTP\" "D:\QlikSense\Data\OBL\FTP\T56Q_OBL002_*.zip"

exit /b

:UnZipFile <ExtractTo> <NewZipFile>
set "vbs=%temp%\_.vbs"
if exist "%vbs%" del /f /q "%vbs%"

(   echo strExtractTo = WScript.Arguments.Item(0^)
    echo strNewZipFile = WScript.Arguments.Item(1^)
    echo WScript.echo strExtractTo,  strNewZipFile
    echo set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)
    echo if not objFSO.FolderExists(strExtractTo^) Then
    echo   fso.CreateFolder(strExtractTo^)
    echo end if
    echo set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application"^)
    echo set FilesInZip = objShell.NameSpace(strNewZipFile^).items
    echo objShell.NameSpace(strExtractTo^).CopyHere(FilesInZip^)
    echo Set objFSO = Nothing
    echo Set objShell = Nothing
) > "%vbs%"

for %%A in ("%~2") do cscript //nologo "%vbs%" "%~1" "%%~A"
if exist "%vbs%" del /f /q "%vbs%"
timeout 20
```

Added argument handling for the VBScript and use a `for` loop to handle the asterisk wildcard used in the zip filenames.